# Getting sliced data between two timeskip database transfer data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, data-transfer

How can I get 'sliced' data and remove the data from database?

I was using two database MySQL and SQL SERVER.

Example:

Yesterday I transfered data from MySql to Sql Server about 1000 rows,
then today I simply deleted 5 rows in MySql then did the transfer again.

So, how can I know which ID was deleted from MySQL then remove it in SQL Server?

I was transferring data using Stored Procedures that check every ID in every loop inserting.

```
foreach($data AS $key => $value){ $this->MsSQL->Exec('exec sp_pendaftar {ID} {NAME}'); }
```

I have stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_pendaftar] @id INT,@name varchar(45) AS DECLARE @id nvarchar(40); SET NOCOUNT ON; SET @id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM t_pendaftar WHERE  id = @id);
IF @id IS NULL BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_pendaftar VALUES(@id,@name); 
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE t_pendaftar SET name = @name WHERE id = @id;
    END;
GO
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand anything of the SQL-Server code, but I would suggest to make a part of the replication via application. So, for the bigger and more dynamical data tables you could define a `delete_pendafter` and a `insert_pendafer` table (and also a `change_pendafter` if needed).

Before you delete from t_pendafter, you select just those rows into `delete_pendafter`. This is even possible with triggers, if that does not slow down the application too much.

On SQL-Server-side I hope you have a `delete`-`join`, so you just remove the deleted rows. In MySQL this would look like

```
DELETE orig 
FROM t_pendafter AS orig 
INNER JOIN delete_pendafter AS del ON del.id = orig.id
```

This solution can be extended to INSERT and CHANGE, but must be done with some care.

Every now and then you should make a full copy, and you should write some checks to ensure the data is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Just got some answer from my partner.
First, grab array `id` from MySQL DB and then grab array id from SQL Server and compare which id that not present in SQL Server using array_diff().

```
$MySQL : array[id] => [11,12,13,15,16,19,25]
$SQL_Server : array[id] => [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25 ]
$array_to_be_deleted : array($SQL_Server , $MySQL)
print_r($array_to_be_deleted);
result would be:
array => [14,17,18,20,21,23,24]
```

Hope anyone can try to correct me.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to this question of a new question?